# Какие способы выхода из вложенных циклов вы знаете?

Tags: java

Собственно вопрос в заголовке - какие способы выхода из вложенных циклов вы знаете?

Чтобы код выглядел компактно, использовалось минимально кода.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        for(int k = 0; k < j; k++)
```

1. Метка

[Ссылка на oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

P.S. Приводите код с примерами.

Comment: присвоение предельных значений :)

Comment: `goto`, `break`, `return`, `throw`

Comment: continue с указание метки внешнего цикла?

Comment: Конечный автомат.

Comment: Вы создаете учебник или тест для курсов по Java? Или может вопрос для олимпиады? Или просто решили создать с вопроса курилку или клуб знатоков?

Comment: Возникла необходимость при решении поставленной задачи - спросил, кто знает какие способы

Comment: Те люди, которые минусуют - если для вас данный вопрос неактуален - проходите мимо либо обосновывайте свои непонятные и никому не нужные минуса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как, соответственно, уже написали в комментариях выше: `break` и `continue`.